# Ubuntu doesn't fully boot - MacbookPro

Tags: boot, usb, macbook-pro

So I installed yesterday Ubuntu from USB stick and everything was fine 'till I rebooted after update (I didn't plug in the wire when I was installing).
Mac informed me about some Moklist (I think I remembered right) error. Then moved on to boot Ubuntu.

Only the issue is that it shows splashscreen and loading the os then I have just black screen with dash blinking in top left corner.

I tried reinstalling from the USB (whiped the HDD for good measure) yet issue still persists.

I'm fairly sure I failed with that Moklist but I don't know how to fix that.

I usually deal with normal PCs with Win where u only need to swear and shout at it for few hours to fix it.

I don't have OSX on that Mac.
It is Macbook Pro 17" late 2008 (if it matters somehow)
I prepared the USB stick according to this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the Nvidia driver. Few reinstalls later eventually skipping installing additional drivers made system to boot normally.
Costed me 8h of fighting with wifi drivers though, still didn't managed to fix it.